# Is this functor a left adjoint?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, quiver

I have a functor $sGrph \to Quiv$ which replaces each edge in a given simple graph with a cospan (and leaves the vertices alone). This functor clearly preserves colimits. Is it a left adjoint?

Comment: Almost. The result should have arrows pointing in to the new vertex.

Comment: So by sGrph, I mean the category of simple graphs. So the functor takes a simple graph and turns it into a quiver by replacing an edge with a new vertex and two arrows pointing inward.

Comment: by adjoint functor theorem if $sGraph$ and $Quiv$ are locally presentable categories then if the functor preserves colimits then it has a left adjoint. Given that Cat is locally presentable and there are forgetful functors from Cat to both categories it would informally seem like such a functor would exist. I cannot seem to write one down however.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. I tried constructing the adjoint, but its hard.

Comment: Here is a discussion on MO chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42768945#42768945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your functor $F.$ Let $2$ denote the two-object one-arrow quiver that looks like $0\to 1.$ Then $|\mathrm{Hom_{Quiv}}(F(K_2),2)|=1,$ but $|\mathrm{Hom_{sGraph}}(K_2,G)|$ is even for any simple graph $G.$ So $F$ cannot be a left adjoint.

To use an adjoint functor theorem to construct a right adjoint you'd really want $\mathrm{sGraph}$ to be cocomplete, but it doesn't have a coequalizer for the two automorphisms of $K_2$ for example.

Comment: Is $|Hom_{sGraph}(K_2,G)|$ even when $G$ is a vertex with no edge? I think its the terminal simple graph, which would imply not.

Comment: @JoeMoeller: there is no graph homomorphism $K_2\to K_1,$ because the edge has to be sent to an edge. I'm assuming the definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I hadn't had my coffee yet.